# How do I access an object by index in a knockout observablearray? Unable to process binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am a totally new to stackoverflow and knockout and I have a question. I would like to access an JSON object by index. It works fine if I add dummy data in my code, but it gives me an error if I add data from JSON and stops.

**Error** 
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Ads()[0].AdContent }" Message: Cannot read property 'AdContent' of undefined

My ViewModel:

```
function AdListModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.Ads = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            self.Ads(data); 
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AdListModel());
```

JSON I receive

```
[{"AdId":6,"AdContent":"sadasdasdsad","CategoryId":1,"CategoryNameRU":"Дом, стройка, ремонт"},{"AdId":12,"AdContent":"asdasd","CategoryId":1,"CategoryNameRU":"Дом, стройка, ремонт"}]
```

My HTML

```
   <div data-bind="text: Ads()[0].AdContent"></div>

   <div data-bind="foreach: Ads">   
      <p data-bind="text: AdId"></p>
      <p data-bind="text: AdContent"></p>
      <p data-bind="text: CategoryId"></p>
      <p data-bind="text: CategoryNameRU"></p>
   </div>
```

So, basically I would like to read just one property in JSON object with index 0 and then display all array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Ads" array is empty until you don't get response on the ajax call. Hence "Ads()[0]" is undefined.

You can use additional check in the binding:

```
<!-- ko if: Ads().length > 0 -->
<div data-bind="text: Ads()[0].AdContent"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Note: "foreach" binding processes empty arrays correctly.